# Fixing picture heights (to avoid overlap with text)

Tags: spacing, diagrams, height

I’m using the `picture` environment (with `linguex`).  However my pictures overlap with the text:

[image]

I've fixed the problem by adding in a rule with zero width and height equivalent to the picture (30 times 0.3ex) plus 1ex (for extra clearance): `\rule[-10ex]{0ex}{10ex}`.  How can I avoid this manual fix?

[image]

---

Separate question: to get characters with ascenders and descenders to align with the baseline of the text, I’m sticking them into boxes with zero height and depth: `\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\omega$}`.  Surely there’s a less verbose way?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mathptmx, qtree, linguex}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ex.   \setlength\unitlength{.3ex}
\begin{picture}(24,-30)
\multiput(2.5,-1.5)(12,-15){2}{\line(20,-30){6}}
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\omega$}}}
\put(12,-15){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\pi$}}}
\put(24,-30){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\varphi$}}}
\end{picture}
\rule[-10ex]{0ex}{10ex}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `picture` environment takes two sets of ordered pairs as arguments. The first is the image dimension (you need a positive number on the y value to have the same effect as the vspace), and the second ordered pair is the coordinates of the lower-left corner of the picture. In this MWE, I use `\begin{picture}(24,33)(0,-30)` to achieve a size large enough (`33`) to avoid the need for the `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mathptmx, qtree, linguex}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ex.   \setlength\unitlength{.3ex}
\begin{picture}(24,33)(0,-30)
\multiput(2.5,-1.5)(12,-15){2}{\line(20,-30){6}}
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\omega$}}}
\put(12,-15){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\pi$}}}
\put(24,-30){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\varphi$}}}
\end{picture}
%\rule[-10ex]{0ex}{10ex}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get, as the OP requests, the numbering at the top of the figure, one way (changing his code the least), is to wrap the `picture` environment in a `\belowbaseline` macro from the `stackengine` package.  There are perhaps other ways inside the picture environment, but I'm not sure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mathptmx, qtree, linguex}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ex.   \setlength\unitlength{.3ex}
\belowbaseline[-5pt]{%
\begin{picture}(24,34)(0,-31)
\multiput(2.5,-1.5)(12,-15){2}{\line(20,-30){6}}
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\omega$}}}
\put(12,-15){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\pi$}}}
\put(24,-30){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\varphi$}}}
\end{picture}%
}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This places phi on the baseline of the example number.  I don't mind this, but it's not conventional.  Is there a way to keep omega on the same line as (1)?

Comment: @DanielHarbour Please see revision.

Comment: @DanielHarbour  Take a look at the package documentation.  It gives a lot of various types of capability, baseline shifting being but one.

Comment: For general reference of anyone reading this: http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.sty

Comment: http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.pdf